# How to pick the image name and image from iPhone photo library in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm doing a pick a images from iPhone photo library or in other way from camera roll. I've done that without any problem. But I need to retrieve the picking the image name from the library. but I cant able to pick the image name from gallery. My requirement is I want to pick the image and image name from photo gallery and send the chat wall.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *image =[[UIImage alloc] init];

    image =[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    NSURL *imagePath = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

//Here I am able to get the image path like this: assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=9F983DBA-EC35-42B8-8773-B597CF782EDD&ext=JPG

    imageName = [imagePath lastPathComponent];

    NSData *imageData;

    NSString *extensionOFImage =[imageName substringFromIndex:[imageName rangeOfString:@"."].location+1 ];

    if ([extensionOFImage isEqualToString:@"jpg"])
    {
        imageData =UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    }
    else
    {
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    }

    int imageSize=imageData.length/1024;

    NSLog(@"imageSize--->%d", imageSize);

    if (imageName!=nil) {

        NSLog(@"imageName--->%@",imageName);

//here the imageName is showing like this “asset.jpg”..

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"no image name found");
    }
}

-(void)sendMessage:(NSString *)messageTxt {

    str=@"Ryan";

    mesText=messageTxt;

    senderImgName=[UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

//here the imageName is showing like this = asset.jpg

//but senderImgName= null.

    NSString *str1=imageName;

    NSLog(@"sender image name is:%@",senderImgName);

    imgData=[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(senderImgName, 0)];

    finalImagePath=[imgData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];

    NSLog(@"Final image path is:%@", finalImagePath);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get the name of image picked through photo library in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314405/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-image-picked-through-photo-library-in-iphone)

Comment: @RonakChaniyara this is not duplicate.. plz if you have any idea plz tell me... i am struck this issue

Comment: @satya have you tried the solution provided in that link ?

Comment: @UmairAfzal yes bro.. but i can't get image name bro..

Answer (score 1):

Use the Photos framework and import Photos/Photos.h

```
#import "Photos/Photos.h"
```

In your imagePickerController function add the following to get the filename of the selected image from the Photo library:

```
NSURL *imagePath = [editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[imagePath] options:nil];
NSString *filename = [[result firstObject] filename];
NSLog(@"[filename ] %@", filename );
```

The result is like this: [filename ] IMG_0012.JPG